# React Native "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

I am running a react-native application on Mac. but I am getting "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager.

Comment: can you share you code where you have used SafeReaView and how have you imported it?

Answer (score 0):

update version of this module by typing following command in terminal:

npm install react-native-safe-area-context@1.0.2

it will solve this problem