# React Native Mapbox - MapboxNavigation was not found in the UIM

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mapbox, native

So I've been trying to integrate `@homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation` I've followed the install instructions found here https://github.com/homeeondemand/react-native-mapbox-navigation to the letter 3 times now. I continue to get the following error, this is from the simulator:

[image: Simulators error]

This is from the console:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "MapboxNavigation" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in MapboxNavigation (at react-native-mapbox-navigation/index.js:6)
    in MapboxNavigation (at ManifestScreen.tsx:37)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Themed.tsx:40)
    in View (at ManifestScreen.tsx:36)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Themed.tsx:40)
    in View (at ManifestScreen.tsx:25)
    in ManifestScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:619)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:612)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:494)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at ManifestTabNavigator.tsx:60)
    in DirectionsNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at BottomTabView.tsx:55)
    in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:172)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:58)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:41)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:166)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at src/index.native.js:123)
    in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:146)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at BottomTabView.tsx:145)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:144)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:45)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at ManifestTabNavigator.tsx:19)
    in ManifestTabNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:619)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:612)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:494)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at navigation/index.tsx:45)
    in RootNavigator (at navigation/index.tsx:29)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at navigation/index.tsx:26)
    in Navigation (at App.tsx:18)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at App.tsx:17)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
- node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "MapboxNavigation" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in MapboxNavigation (at react-native-mapbox-navigation/index.js:6)
    in MapboxNavigation (at ManifestScreen.tsx:37)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Themed.tsx:40)
    in View (at ManifestScreen.tsx:36)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Themed.tsx:40)
    in View (at ManifestScreen.tsx:25)
    in ManifestScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:619)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:612)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:494)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at ManifestTabNavigator.tsx:60)
    in DirectionsNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at BottomTabView.tsx:55)
    in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:172)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:58)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:41)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:166)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at src/index.native.js:123)
    in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:146)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at BottomTabView.tsx:145)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:144)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:45)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at ManifestTabNavigator.tsx:19)
    in ManifestTabNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:619)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:612)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:494)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at navigation/index.tsx:45)
    in RootNavigator (at navigation/index.tsx:29)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at navigation/index.tsx:26)
    in Navigation (at App.tsx:18)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at App.tsx:17)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15257:32 in logCapturedError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15361:20 in logError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16597:12 in update.callback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7106:2 in callCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7127:20 in commitUpdateQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15801:25 in commitLifeCycles
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18744:22 in commitLayoutEffects
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18483:29 in commitRootImpl
* [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18317:17 in commitRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17697:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
* [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17718:28 in batchedUpdates$1
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2492:29 in batchedUpdates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2638:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2767:27 in receiveTouches
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

This is code for the file where I am trying to use the mapbox package:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';
import styles from '../components/styles';
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {Image} from 'react-native';

import MapboxNavigation from '@homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation';

export default function ManifestScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.padlessContainer}>
        <MapboxNavigation
          origin={[-97.760288, 30.273566]}
          destination={[-97.918842, 30.494466]}
          shouldSimulateRoute={true}
          onLocationChange={(event: any) => {
            const { latitude, longitude } = event.nativeEvent;
          }}
          onRouteProgressChange={(event: any) => {
            const {
              distanceTraveled,
              durationRemaining,
              fractionTraveled,
              distanceRemaining,
            } = event.nativeEvent;
          }}
          onError={(event: any) => {
            const { message } = event.nativeEvent;
          }}
          onCancelNavigation={() => {
            // User tapped the "X" cancel button in the nav UI
            // or canceled via the OS system tray on android.
            // Do whatever you need to here.
          }}
          onArrive={() => {
            // Called when you arrive at the destination.
          }}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I checked and made sure I had the correct native extensions installed in my `/ios/pods` directory:

[image: Pods directory]

I also made sure I had all the needed packages installed in the node_modules:

[image: Node modules directory]

I also seen this issue, which seemed similar so I tried to autolink the missing package that was listed in the simulator errors:

[React Native "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034686/react-native-rncsafeareaview-was-not-found-in-the-uimanager#answer-61329389)

That didn't help either, I've been trouble shooting for 3-4 days trying to get this resolved, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Where you able to fix this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to fix the same error.

Link the package manually

```
npx react-native link @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation
```

or

```
react-native link @homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation
```

Check if this line appear on your Podfile:

```
pod 'react-native-mapbox-navigation', :path => '../node_modules/@homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation'
```

Run `pod install` in ios folder

Try to build again.

--

if you see the following error:

> [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static
> libraries:
>
> The Swift pod `react-native-mapbox-navigation` depends upon
> `React-Core`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets
> generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift
> when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!`
> globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for
> particular dependencies.

change

```
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
```

to

```
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React', :modular_headers => true
```

Comment: Alright I will try to give it a whirl! Thanks

Comment: this was the response when i typed that command: `error Unrecognized command "link".
info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.`

Comment: @Akash Did you try `npx react-native link`?